# Given two different metrics on the same set, define a third different from the other two.

Tags: metric-spaces

Given two different metrics defined on the same set, define a third different from the other other two. Prove that the third metric is, indeed, a metric.

EDIT: Apologies, posted it before I could complete the post. This is a very general question, making it difficult to approach. Could adding the two metrics create a third different from the other two? Where do I go from there?

Comment: Apologies, I posted it before I could complete the post. Alex has kindly provided the definition of a metric before.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
If you have $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ as metrics, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}
d_i(x,y) & \ge 0 & \forall x,y\in X\\
d_i(x,y) & = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=y & \forall x,y \in X \\
d_i(x,y) & \le d_i(x,z) + d_i(z,y) & \forall x,y,z\in X \\
d_i(x,y) & = d_i(y,x) & \forall x,y\in X
\end{align*}$$
How would some sort of **average** of the two metrics work with the axioms?

---

If you've looked into it, you can try to show (not hard), that the entire cone of metrics defined by
$$\langle d_1, d_2 \rangle_+ := \{ d(x,y) := \alpha d_1(x,y) + \beta d_2(x,y) \ | \alpha,\beta \ge 0, \alpha\cdot \beta > 0\}$$
all satisfy the axioms.

Comment: Oh, I think your hint is great! Let me work on it...

Comment: Hmm, could you please critique my proof for the second part of the definition? In particular, the left-hand side of the biconditional:

Comment: Let M_1(x,y) = M_2(x,y) = 0. Then, x = y. And since M_3(x,y) = M_1(x,y) + M_2(x,y), M_3(x,y) = 0.

Comment: If you mean
$$M_3(x,x) = M_1(x,x) + M_2(x,x) \stackrel{\text{A2 for }M_1,M_2}= 0+0 = 0$$
That's fine. The other way around requires some (minor) work though.

Comment: Great, thank you! Hmm, I thought the other way was just as easy. Here's my proof:

Comment: Let x = y. Then, M_1(x,y) = 0 and M_2(x,y) = 0. And since M_3(x,y) = M_1(x,y) + M_2(x,y), M_3(x,y) = 0 + 0 and M_3(x,y) = 0.

Comment: Note that "the other way" is $$$$
Let $M_3(x,y) = 0$, then (_reasons_) $\Rightarrow x=y$

Comment: Oh, I see. Then how about this: Let M_3(x,y) = 0. Then, M_1(x,y) + M_2(x,y) = 0. But since metrics must be greater than or equal to 0, for the sum to be true, M_1 and M_2 must 0.

Comment: @Brian That's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is $M_3(x,y) = M_1(x,y) + M_2(x,y) $.

Using the symmetry property on $M_1$ and $M_2$ it is trivial to show $M_3$ is also symmetric.
Similarly for most of the other properties.

The hardest property to pr0ve is that 
$$M_3(x,z) \leq M_3(x,y) + $M_3(y,z)$ but even that falls out of the inequalities for $M_1$ and $M_2$ easily.

Comment: "hard"? It's still a one-liner xD

Comment: Yeah, how's this for the triangle inequality: Consider M_1(x,y) and M_2(x,y). Then, M_1(x,y) <= M_1(x,z) + M_2(z,y) and M_2(x,y) <= M_1(x,z) + M_2(z,y). Then, M_1(x,y) + M_2(x,y) = M_3(x,y) <= M_1(x,z) + M_2(x,z) + M_1(z,y) + M_2(z,y).

Comment: Then, you sub M_3(x,z) for M_1(x,z) + M_2(x,z) and M_3(z,y) for M_1(z,y) + M_2(z,y).